# JavaScript which Opens URL and echo its content in a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript which Opens URL and echo its content in a Div.

I want this Script to Open A lot of URLs one by one.

I Tried Below Code. Not working, I'm seeing Network Tab. No Request is initiating.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/3/

```
<input id="start" value="1">
<input id="end" value="100">
<a href="#" id="submit">start</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>


<script>

$("#submit").click(function(){

    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;

    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;

   for (i = start; i < end; i++) { 


    var url = $(this).attr('href');

     url = 'http://example.com/checker.php?id=' + i;

    $('#target').load(url); sleep(1000);


}

});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the click function is firing?

Comment: @Soviut, Yes. i placed a div element with #submit for it.

Comment: @Soviut, I'm sorry, mis-understood. YES I"M SURE ITS NOT FIRING AT ALL.  :(

Comment: Please provide a snippet or jsFiddle with your code. Also `sleep` does not exist.

Comment: @jcaron, thankyou for coming to the rescue. here it is https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/

Comment: You're missing a `$` at the beginning of your JS. You're missing jQuery (click on the gears next to `Javascript` to select it). You're using `sleep` which does not exist.

Comment: @jcaron, Thankyou. Updated - https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/2/ but still not working :( and any solution for Sleep() ?

Comment: Beyond the fact that your insecure (and non-existent) URL is not allowed to load in this context, it seems to work. You may want to consider `setTimeout`, though of course you'll need to change your logic somewhat as it won't be a straightforward loop.

Comment: @jcaron, actually the URL I used in JSFiddle actually exists [200 status]. Sleep [timeout] is not much important for me, so no problem with that. but the code is still not working at all :(

Comment: @jcaron now please check https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/5/ All working good. expect the Sleep [timeout thing]. can you suggest any other smart solution to send URL Requests one by one, but not in bulk..

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` is a very old way of waiting for the document ready. You just need `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: @Soviut, if you don't mind. I understand how to do it, but i don't understand where to implement it as it has a FOR function. can you please implement the wait function for me and give the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work on JSFiddle because it uses https and the content you're trying to load is on an http domain. If you open the javascript console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in Chrome), you can see errors about `Mixed Content`.

> VM69 jquery-3.1.1.js:9536 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/2/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/checker.php?id=1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just changed the URL to HTTPS Version. 

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/3/  the https url also exists and gives a 200 status.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. Special thanks to @jcaron too.

Please check, https://jsfiddle.net/at4gdnng/5/

its sending all requests at a time [acting like DDOS Attack] any chance we can slow the requests one by one ..

Comment: @JohnMathews that's a totally different question. Search StackOverflow for the answer first and, if you don't find it, create another question.